# Android : launch mode for activities

Tags: android

I have multiple activities in my application .
The flow for activities is

A->B->C...

A->D->E...

A->F->G..

....

And each has a back button to go back to previous activity and home to go back to A.

My question is when i launch each of these as singletask, i can visible feel fast switching between activities when i click back or home. I dont see any issues if i keep them as singletask.

BUt are there any issues that i am verlooking if i keep the activities as singletask in my application. Thanks a lot for your time and help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there are issues in changing the behaviour mode of activity from mainfest.xml, When you will press the home button for android home screen and get back to the application the previous activity will be gone and will finish the application, then better is to use intent instead using single task mode, you can use flags with intent to cleat the activity stacks..and by launching the mode in single task you are changing the systems settings, why dont you keep the launch mode and give it to system for handling the activities..!

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),A.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

Comment: The point about application finishing when home is really good. I noticed that point only after this read. Thank you.

Can you pleas explain "you can use flags with intent to cleat the activity stacks." Which context this will be used

Comment: Its like when you want to go ur application's menu (i.e. A), just add the flag to your intent, that will clear the activities which were called after A and will give u directly to A and else activites will be destroyed if they are not finished... try this flag..i edited the answer..

Comment: Ok , Here one more doubt : if we set the flag other actvities will be cleared from stack, else they will be destryed . Can you please explain what is meant by clear from stack. Are they not actually getting destroyed, Next time when that activity which is cleared when started, it will not be launched but brough back to stack ? am i correct ?

Comment: Activity stack maintains the activities which are not finished, When you will call the intent with that intent flag that i mentioned, the activity stack will be clear and finish the activities between your current activity and activity on which you want to go...and if you are not calling that intent flag then the activities between ur current activity and on which u want to go will not be cleared and finished..and they will appear when you will call the close the application, those activities will come to your screen again..

Comment: On testing i see that if i had launched as single task and come back to activity A , A is just resumed ie its not onCreate of A that is gettiong called. So good no reinitilaisation.

 tried with default launch mode, and tried launching A from B with flag "clear activity top" but what i see is that As onCreate is getting called again. 

What is the difference in this behaviour, I dont want A "to be created " again and again as i do all my initialisations here

Comment: ok,
then put the launch mode of A as a single Task then because, already its a first activity...so u will not need get the fist activity twice on screen, and if its first activity of your application then, i think you should not have any problem on recreate of that activity..

Comment: Suppose I have a launcher activity A , and then two activities B and C. If I am on activity C and presses home, then how can I get the same activity C on resume? please help.thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

A "standard" or "singleTop" activity can be instantiated many
times. They can belong to multiple tasks, and a given task can
have multiple instances of the same activity.
 In contrast, "singleTask" and "singleInstance" activities are
limited to just one instance. Since these activities are at the
root of a task, this limitation means that there is never more
than a single instance of the task on the device at one time.

The clearTaskOnLaunch attribute If this attribute is set to
"true" in the root activity of a task, the stack is cleared down
to the root activity whenever the user leaves the task and
returns to it. In other words, it's the polar opposite of
alwaysRetainTaskState(which u can use if u want to retain all activities in a stsck). The user always returns to the task in
its initial state, even after a momentary absence or even after pressing home in ur case.